# Creating a spinner using SVG and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, svg

I'm trying to create a spinner using SVG and javascript. The problem is that it doesn't work accurately. It has start and stop functions. When start is clicked, it delays before animating, and when i stop it stops well but fails to start if I click start again.

Currently, It's not working in IE9 and IE11. If there're hacks that I don't know of.

How would you animate this using [RapahelJS](http://raphaeljs.com)?

http://plnkr.co/edit/FC2qiZumzgjKSJOs6Zm5?p=preview

```
var spinner = function() {
var interval;

    var transition = function() {
        var path = document.querySelector('#spinner-wrapper .spinner #main-path');
        path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'none';
        path.style.strokeDasharray = '205.951, 205.951';
        path.style.strokeDashoffset = 430;
        path.getBoundingClientRect();
        path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
        path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset 3s linear';
    };

    var startInterval = function(time) {
        return interval = setInterval(function() {
            transition();
        }, time);
    };

    return {
        start : function() {
            startInterval(2700);
        },
        stop : function() {
            startInterval(0);
            clearInterval(start());
        }
    };
```

};

Comment: I might suggest an easier method... use CSS to rotate a static image.  (Of course that doesn't work if you need to change aspects of the image itself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not have a complete code answer for you. However, I can tell you why you are having some issues.

First, the reason for the delay is that you are saying `setInterval(function(){...},2700);` Which means that it will call that function in 2.7 seconds and continue to call it every 2.7 seconds after that. Try adding in this piece of code before `setInterval()`

```
setTimeout(transition,0);
```

This will call your transition function immediately once. Then setInterval will call it 2.7 seconds later.

The reason for the issue with not restarting, I believe, is that you are creating multiple intervals and only clearing one of them. For some reason, the `var interval` is not accessible from the `stop()` function, likely due to some scoping issues. So in order to fix this issue, you will need to restructure your code some.

**EDIT**

Check out this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/DLaQ21NqBtB79khsN9hE?p=preview .
Hopefully it does what you want it to do. Code:

```
var spinner = function() {
  this.transition = function() {
    var path = document.querySelector('#spinner-wrapper .spinner #main-path');
    path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'none';
    path.style.strokeDasharray = '205.951';
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = 430;
    path.getBoundingClientRect();
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
    path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset 3s linear';
};

  this.startInterval = function(immediate,time) {
    if(immediate){
      setTimeout(transition,0);
    }
    this.interval = setInterval(function() {
      transition();
    }, time);
    return this.interval;
  };

  this.start = function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    startInterval(true,2700);
  };

  this.stop = function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    startInterval(false,0);
  };

  return this;
};
```

Comment: It's not working in IE11. Any clue how to make it work in IE11?

Comment: @user730009 Can you describe what you mean? Does it show any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: Well, it doesn't animate. Clicking on the start button does nothing. I don't see any error messages. [http://plnkr.co/edit/FC2qiZumzgjKSJOs6Zm5?p=preview]

Comment: Here's another version. But still doesn't work in IE11. [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/SkGK6PNtwwhhgHV3s2Zv?p=preview)

Comment: @user730009 I'm not sure why it doesn't work in IE11. As for using RaphaelJS, I would suggest creating a new question.

Comment: I need it to support IE11 at least.

Comment: I really don't know. I would recommend creating a new question.